# Filling a web form using VBA

Tags: vba

So I have been given the task to create new users in the company I work for website. I was given an excel sheet of 100 + usernames and email addresses. I did not want to have to manually do it so is decided to try and write a program. I have never touched VB before, and this is how far I have been able to reach. It works for the first run through the while loop but then I receive an error:

> Run-time error '91'
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

When I try to debug this error, This line in my code becomes highlighted:

```
   IE.document.GetElementsbyname("user_login")(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(j, i) ' sets login info
```

In my Excel Spreadsheet, the email addresses are same as the login info, and they are links to send an email via outlook. I will see if this is causing my error, but in the meantime, I wanted to get a second pair of eyes on this. Thank you for reading this. this is my first post on here so I apologize if it isn't as informative as you'd like

Here is the rest of my code so far

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
Dim IE As Object
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'create new instance of IE
Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim x As Integer
 Dim y As Integer
 Dim s As String
 s = "paswd" ' pasword setting
 i = 4  ' column  D for email input
      j = 50 ' row to start
    x = 9 ' column I    For last name input
    y = 10 'column j for  last name
'you want to use open IE window. Easiest way I know of is via title bar.
While j < 121

Wait
        IE.Navigate "website link"
                'go to web page listed inside quotes
    IE.Visible = True
        While IE.busy
            DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
            Wend

        IE.document.GetElementsbyname("user_login")(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(j, i) ' sets login info
        IE.document.GetElementsbyname("email")(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(j, i) '  sets email address
        IE.document.GetElementsbyname("first_name")(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(j, y) ' sets first name
        IE.document.GetElementsbyname("last_name")(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(j, x) ' sets last name
        Set elementcol = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button button-secondary wp-generate-pw hide-if-no-js")
             elementcol.Item(0).Click 'shows the password
                While IE.busy
                     DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
                Wend
          IE.document.GetElementsbyname("pass1-text")(0).Value = s 'sets the password
         Wait 
        Set elementcol = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pw-checkbox")
            elementcol.Item(0).Click ' clicks confirmation of weak password choice
                While IE.busy
                    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
                Wend
        Set elementcol = IE.document.GetElementsbyname("send_user_notification")
            elementcol.Item(0).Click ' unclicks send new user email
                 While IE.busy
                    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
                Wend
       IE.document.getElementByID("createusersub").Click ' clicks add new user

                While IE.busy
                     DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
                Wend
        j = j + 1
         While IE.busy
                     DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
                Wend


Wend
End Sub
Sub Wait()
    Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
End Sub
```

EDIT: THIS ERROR ONLY appears after 5 runs through my loop

Answer (score 0):

The cache is probably clogged up from all the looping.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindFirstUrlCacheGroup Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal dwFilter As Long, _
    ByRef lpSearchCondition As Long, _
    ByVal dwSearchCondition As Long, _
    ByRef lpGroupId As Date, _
    ByRef lpReserved As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindNextUrlCacheGroup Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hFind As Long, _
    ByRef lpGroupId As Date, _
    ByRef lpReserved As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheGroup Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal sGroupID As Date, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByRef lpReserved As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindFirstUrlCacheEntry Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FindFirstUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
    ByVal lpszUrlSearchPattern As String, _
    ByRef lpFirstCacheEntryInfo As INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO, _
    ByRef lpdwFirstCacheEntryInfoBufferSize As Long) As Long

Private Type INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO
    dwStructSize As Long
    szRestOfData(1024) As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
    ByVal lpszUrlName As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindNextUrlCacheEntry Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FindNextUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
    ByVal hEnumHandle As Long, _
    ByRef lpNextCacheEntryInfo As INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO, _
    ByRef lpdwNextCacheEntryInfoBufferSize As Long) As Long

Private Const CACHGROUP_SEARCH_ALL = &H0
Private Const ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES = 18
Private Const ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259
Private Const CACHEGROUP_FLAG_FLUSHURL_ONDELETE = &H2
Private Const BUFFERSIZE = 2048

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim sGroupID As Date
    Dim hGroup As Long
    Dim hFile As Long
    Dim sEntryInfo As INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO
    Dim iSize As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Delete the groups
    hGroup = FindFirstUrlCacheGroup(0, 0, 0, 0, sGroupID, 0)

    ' To avoid error using it with IE4 as FindFirstUrlCacheGroup is not implemented
    If Err.Number <> 453 Then
        If (hGroup = 0) And (Err.LastDllError <> 2) Then
            MsgBox "An error occurred enumerating the cache groups" & Err.LastDllError
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Err.Clear
    End If

    If (hGroup <> 0) Then
        'we succeeded in finding the first cache group.. enumerate and
        'delete
        Do
            If (0 = DeleteUrlCacheGroup(sGroupID, CACHEGROUP_FLAG_FLUSHURL_ONDELETE, 0)) Then

               ' To avoid error using it with IE4 as FindFirstUrlCacheGroup is not implemented
               If Err.Number <> 453 Then
                 MsgBox "Error deleting cache group " & Err.LastDllError
                 Exit Sub
               Else
                  Err.Clear
               End If
            End If
            iSize = BUFFERSIZE
            If (0 = FindNextUrlCacheGroup(hGroup, sGroupID, iSize)) And (Err.LastDllError <> 2) Then
                MsgBox "Error finding next url cache group! - " & Err.LastDllError
            End If
        Loop Until Err.LastDllError = 2
    End If

  ' Delete the files
    sEntryInfo.dwStructSize = 80
    iSize = BUFFERSIZE
    hFile = FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(0, sEntryInfo, iSize)
    If (hFile = 0) Then
        If (Err.LastDllError = ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) Then
            GoTo done
        End If
        MsgBox "ERROR: FindFirstUrlCacheEntry - " & Err.LastDllError
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do
        If (0 = DeleteUrlCacheEntry(sEntryInfo.szRestOfData(0))) _
            And (Err.LastDllError <> 2) Then
            Err.Clear
        End If
        iSize = BUFFERSIZE
        If (0 = FindNextUrlCacheEntry(hFile, sEntryInfo, iSize)) And (Err.LastDllError <> ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) Then
            MsgBox "Error:  Unable to find the next cache entry - " & Err.LastDllError
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop Until Err.LastDllError = ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS
done:
    MsgBox "cache cleared"
    Command1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?440508-Clear-IE-Browser-Cache-and-History-with-VBA